# NSCalendar components:fromDate: not filling NSCalendarUnitHour

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I have a call to NScalendar components:fromDate: that fills all the values specified in the listed components except for NSCalendarUnitHour. Can anyone help me find out why?

```
NSCalendar* _cal = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[_cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSDateComponents* resultComponents = [_cal components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:result]; 
//result is 2018-03-18 05:48:36 +0000

//resultComponents 
//<NSDateComponents: 0x60400014f0a0>
//Month: 3
//Leap month: no
//Day: 18
//Hour: 0
//Minute: 48
```

Why would Hour be set to 0?

Comment: What time zone are you in? When it's 05:48 in UTC, what time is it in your time zone?

Comment: Why do you say that the hour isn't filled? You show it's value in your question. It's value is `0`. You live a timezone that is 5 hours earlier than UTC. Your code is working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions from @rmaddy and @Ken Thomases alerted me to the fact that my question did not take into account my current -5 timezone. I thought my timezone was -6 and so I was expecting any value other than 0. (Happy daylight savings...)

My solution to not worry about changing timezones was to change to this:

```
[_cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

Comment: It depends on what timezone you want to work with. Do you want to get the components of `result` in local time or UTC time? That determines which timezone to set on the calendar.